# asp.net codebehind auto file open in frame

Tags: asp.net

I want to open an PDF file but when the code runs i'll get an empty new webpage. 
This is my code to open de pdf in a new window automatic in code behind

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
 "OpenWin", "<script>window.open('" + pdfPath + "')</script>");
```

the new window url: about:blank

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thx

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your browser isn't recognizing the type of script to run, or that the pdfPath isn't being passed to the method. Could you first build the script literal then print it, to ensure you're passing the correct value?

Also, perhaps it should be:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
"OpenWin", "<script type=text/javascript>window.open('" + pdfPath + "')</script>");
```

Edit: the issue could be that you're trying to load a file with an address that references the local file system instead of relative to the web server. Try exposing it in the web application's directory (so that its on the local domain, as far as IIS is concerned) and loading it that way?

Comment: Still doesnt work. 
The pdfPath parameter looks something like this:
C:\\folder\\folder\\folder\\folder\\BarcodeReport.pdf

When i put this path hard into the code it still doesnt work

Comment: Is this a desktop application or a web application? It may be that the file needs a URI relative to the IIS, so that you can serve it as localhost/example.pdf instead of off the local file system.

Comment: It's a web application in asp.net

Comment: If you look at a stack trace in your dev console, you may see that you're getting a cross-site scripting error, trying to load the pdf from a "different" domain. I'd try what I suggested above and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your **pdf** file available in your web application. And you should replace the `pdfPath` with the `pdfUrl` so that your generated HTML to be similar to this:

```
<script type=text/javascript>window.open('/folder/BarcodeReport.pdf')</script>
```

Where `/folder/BarcodeReport.pdf` is an absolute path for your app (ex: http://yourapp.com/folder/BarcodeReport.pdf) or a relative one: `folder/BarcodeReport.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ResolveUrl in c#

```
<script type=text/javascript>window.open(ResolveUrl('~/folder/BarcodeReport.pdf'))</script>
```